# Browser reports "too much recursion" in minesweeper clone

Tags: javascript, php, html, recursion

I'm making a Minesweeper game. The browser says "too much recursion". Could you please see the code and correct the part where I've made a mistake?

```
<?php

/*
    Basic PHP code for generating a table 8x8 with every button a unique id 
*/

    $tableDesign = "<table>";
    $id = 1;

    for($i=0; $i<8; $i++){

        $tableDesign .= "<tr>";
        for($j=0; $j<8; $j++){

            $tableDesign .= "<td><button id='num_$id' onclick='get_button(this.id)'></button></td>";
            $id++;
        }
        $tableDesign .= "</tr>";
    }
    $tableDesign .= "</table>";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mine Sweeper Ver. 0.1</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        td {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
        button {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        img {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        .table{
            float: left;
            width: 550px;
        }
        .switch_command {
            padding-top: 40px;
            font-size: 22px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table">
        <?php echo $tableDesign; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="switch_command">
        Switch to protect from Expload: <input id="check" type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var randomMinesLocation      = new Array(); // this array will contain the id number part of the mines

        var mineProtecition          = new Array(); // this array will contain the mine with flags to not be abled to open when the player clicks on it
        var emptyCells               = new Array(); // this array will contain the empty cells opened to prevent the recursion going through the same cell again 

        // this while loop is responsible for generating 10 different mines in random from 1 to 64
        while (randomMinesLocation.length < 10) {

            index = randomMinesLocation.length;
            match = false;
            position = Math.floor((Math.random() * 64) + 1);

            for (i = 0; i < randomMinesLocation.length; i++) {

                if(position == randomMinesLocation[i])
                    match = true;
            }

            if(!match) randomMinesLocation[index] = position;
        }

        // I made this check function to prevent to equal id to be contained to the openedEmptyCells array which will be used to open the cells in cooperation with another function
        function checkForEqualVal(valToTest, openedEmptyCells) {
            match = false;
            if (openedEmptyCells.length == 0) {
                openedEmptyCells.push(valToTest);
            } else {
                for (i = 0; i < openedEmptyCells.length; i++){
                    if(openedEmptyCells[i][1] == valToTest[1]) {
                        match = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!match) {
                    openedEmptyCells.push(valToTest);
                }
            }
            return openedEmptyCells;
        }

        function logic_game(idNumericPart, randomMinesLocation, openedEmptyCells = []) {

            match = false;
            numberOfMinesNear =  0; 
            canditateCells = [];

                for (j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                    if (idNumericPart <= 8 && j == 1 || idNumericPart > 56 && j == -1 ) continue;
                    for(k= -1; k <= 1; k++){
                        if(((idNumericPart - 1) % 8 == 0 && k == -1) || (idNumericPart % 8 == 0 && k == 1))
                            continue;

                        idNumericPartOfNear = idNumericPart - (j * 8) + k;

                        if(j != 0 && k == 0 || j == 0 && k != 0 || j != 0 && k != 0)

                                canditateCells.push(idNumericPartOfNear);

                        for(i=0; i<10; i++){                
                            if(idNumericPart == randomMinesLocation[i]){
                                match = true; 
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(idNumericPartOfNear == randomMinesLocation[i])
                                numberOfMinesNear++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(match)
                    openedEmptyCells = checkForEqualVal([true, idNumericPart], openedEmptyCells);
                else if(numberOfMinesNear > 0){
                    openedEmptyCells = checkForEqualVal([numberOfMinesNear, idNumericPart], openedEmptyCells);
                }
                else{

                    openedEmptyCells = checkForEqualVal([false, idNumericPart], openedEmptyCells);
                    for(i=0; i<canditateCells.length; i++){
                        matchedBtw = false;
                        for(j=0; j<emptyCells.length; j++){
                            if(canditateCells[i] == emptyCells[j])
                                matchedBtw = true;
                                break;
                        }
                        if(!matchedBtw)
                            openedEmptyCells = logic_game(canditateCells[i], randomMinesLocation, openedEmptyCells);
                    }
                }
            return openedEmptyCells;    
        }

        function printToScreen(value, idNumericPart){

                if(typeof(value) === 'boolean' && value){
                    document.getElementById("num_" + idNumericPart).parentElement.innerHTML = '<img src="mine.png">';   
                }
                else if(typeof(value) === 'number'){
                    document.getElementById("num_" + idNumericPart).parentElement.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
                    document.getElementById("num_" + idNumericPart).parentElement.innerHTML = value;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("num_" + idNumericPart).parentElement.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
                    document.getElementById("num_" + idNumericPart).parentElement.innerHTML = '';       
                }
        }

        function get_button(id){

            idNumericPart = id.substring(4);
            checkValue = document.getElementById("check").checked;
            matchCheckForMineProtect = false;

            if(checkValue){

                for(i=0; i<mineProtecition.length; i++){

                    if(mineProtecition[i] == idNumericPart){

                        matchCheckForMineProtect = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(matchCheckForMineProtect){
                    mineProtecition.splice(i, 1);
                    valueToBeSubstitude = '<button id="' + id + '" onclick="get_button(this.id)"></button>';
                }
                else{
                    mineProtecition.push(idNumericPart);
                    valueToBeSubstitude = '<button id="' + id + '" style="background: url(' + 'flag.png' + ') no-repeat; background-size: 40px 40px;" onclick="get_button(this.id)"></button>';
                }

                document.getElementById(id).parentElement.innerHTML = valueToBeSubstitude;
            }
            else {
                matchProtected = false;
                for(i=0; i<mineProtecition.length; i++){

                    if(mineProtecition[i] == idNumericPart){
                        matchProtected = true;
                        break;
                    }   
                }

                if(!matchProtected){

                    result = logic_game(idNumericPart, randomMinesLocation);
                    for(i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                        printToScreen(result[i][0], result[i][1]);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you been able to step through the program at all? Can you place some console.log() statements with simple messages like 'board created', 'mines placed' etc. Then you will get a better idea where the problem is.

Comment: btw I just edited your post to make it clearer, your code is PHP not javascript.

Comment: @edzillion actually it's both.

Comment: your're right. I am getting confused. I will edit some more ;)

Comment: also, did you get any console.log()s?

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the php in your code with java-script  (see modified code below) and adding console.log to the method calls allowed for the location of the infinite recursion loop to be located, giving an output in the console of:

```
> logic_game(15)
minesweeper.html:116 randomMinesLocation
minesweeper.html:117 (10) [10, 56, 36, 33, 3, 14, 24, 54, 2, 13]
minesweeper.html:118 openedEmptyCells
minesweeper.html:119 [Array(2)]
minesweeper.html:115 logic_game(24)
minesweeper.html:116 randomMinesLocation
minesweeper.html:117 (10) [10, 56, 36, 33, 3, 14, 24, 54, 2, 13]
minesweeper.html:118 openedEmptyCells
minesweeper.html:119 (2) [Array(2), Array(2)]
minesweeper.html:115 logic_game(15)
minesweeper.html:116 randomMinesLocation
minesweeper.html:117 (10) [10, 56, 36, 33, 3, 14, 24, 54, 2, 13]
minesweeper.html:118 openedEmptyCells
minesweeper.html:119 (3) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
minesweeper.html:115 logic_game(24)
minesweeper.html:116 randomMinesLocation
minesweeper.html:117 (10) [10, 56, 36, 33, 3, 14, 24, 54, 2, 13]
minesweeper.html:118 openedEmptyCells
minesweeper.html:119 (3) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
```

I can be seen that the  logic_game call to id 15, called l logic_game with id 24 which in turn called logic_game to id 15 which continues as an infinite recursion loop.

To answer the question itself, which is not a correct fix, a fix is to an id stack:

> var idStack =[];

For each recursive call to logic_game function check the stack to make sure the function has already not been called for that id, and if it has return from the function to end the infinite recursion.

> function logic_game(idNumericPart, randomMinesLocation,
>   openedEmptyCells = []) {          // prevent infinite recursion loop;             if
>   (idStack.indexOf(idNumericPart)>-1) {
>                 console.log('infinite loop detected');
>                 return;             }

If the id was not already called then add it to the stack and continue the function.

> // push the id to the idStack so we can tell if this function enters
>   an infinite recursion loop;
>           idStack.push(idNumericPart);

Finally, clear the idStack on each button click so that ids are only tracked for each recursive loop.

> ```
>     function get_button(id){
>         // clear the button ID stack so we can track recursive calls per button click to assure that will only be one call per id per button game;
>         idStack = [];
> ```

We now have prevented the issue asked in the question, solving the problem of too much recursion. However, you'll see that there are other logic errors in the code that need to be fixed:

> minesweeper.html:180 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'parentElement' of null
>       at printToScreen (minesweeper.html:180)
>       at get_button (minesweeper.html:233)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (minesweeper.html:1)

Here's the modified code, replacing the php with javascript, which can now be ran locally in the browser without crashing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mine Sweeper Ver. 0.1</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        td {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
        button {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        img {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }
        .table{
            float: left;
            width: 550px;
        }
        .switch_command {
            padding-top: 40px;
            font-size: 22px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
    <script>

    function getTableDesign()
    {
        var tableDesign = "<table>";
        var id = 1;

        for(var i=0; i<8; i++){

            tableDesign += "<tr>";
            for(var j=0; j<8; j++){

               tableDesign += "<td><button id='num_" + id + "' onclick='get_button(this.id)'></button></td>";
               id++;
            }
            tableDesign += "</tr>";
        }
        tableDesign += "</table>";
        return tableDesign;
    }
    </script>
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#tblTableDesign').html(getTableDesign());
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table" id="tblTableDesign">

    </div>
    <div class="switch_command">
        Switch to protect from Expload: <input id="check" type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var randomMinesLocation      = new Array(); // this array will contain the id number part of the mines

        var mineProtecition          = new Array(); // this array will contain the mine with flags to not be abled to open when the player clicks on it
        var emptyCells               = new Array(); // this array will contain the empty cells opened to prevent the recursion going through the same cell again 

        var idStack =[];
        // this while loop is responsible for generating 10 different mines in random from 1 to 64
        while (randomMinesLocation.length < 10) {

            index = randomMinesLocation.length;
            match = false;
            position = Math.floor((Math.random() * 64) + 1);

            for (i = 0; i < randomMinesLocation.length; i++) {

                if(position == randomMinesLocation[i])
                    match = true;
            }

            if(!match) randomMinesLocation[index] = position;
        }

        // I made this check function to prevent to equal id to be contained to the openedEmptyCells array which will be used to open the cells in cooperation with another function
        function checkForEqualVal(valToTest, openedEmptyCells) {
            match = false;
            if (openedEmptyCells.length == 0) {
                openedEmptyCells.push(valToTest);
            } else {
                for (i = 0; i < openedEmptyCells.length; i++){
                    if(openedEmptyCells[i][1] == valToTest[1]) {
                        match = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!match) {
                    openedEmptyCells.push(valToTest);
                }
            }
            return openedEmptyCells;
        }

        function logic_game(idNumericPart, randomMinesLocation, openedEmptyCells = []) {
            // prevent infinite recursion loop;
            if (idStack.indexOf(idNumericPart)>-1) {
                console.log('infinite loop detected');
                return;
            }
            // push the id to the idStack so we can tell if this function enters an infinite recursion loop;
            idStack.push(idNumericPart); 
            console.log('logic_game('+ idNumericPart +')');
            console.log('randomMinesLocation');
            console.log(randomMinesLocation);
            console.log('openedEmptyCells');
            console.log(openedEmptyCells);
            match = false;
            numberOfMinesNear =  0; 
            canditateCells = [];

                for (j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                    if (idNumericPart <= 8 && j == 1 || idNumericPart > 56 && j == -1 ) continue;
                    for(k= -1; k <= 1; k++){
                        if(((idNumericPart - 1) % 8 == 0 && k == -1) || (idNumericPart % 8 == 0 && k == 1))
                            continue;

                        idNumericPartOfNear = idNumericPart - (j * 8) + k;

                        if(j != 0 && k == 0 || j == 0 && k != 0 || j != 0 && k != 0)

                                canditateCells.push(idNumericPartOfNear);

                        for(i=0; i<10; i++){                
                            if(idNumericPart == randomMinesLocation[i]){
                                match = true; 
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(idNumericPartOfNear == randomMinesLocation[i])
                                numberOfMinesNear++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(match)
                    openedEmptyCells = checkForEqualVal([true, idNumericPart], openedEmptyCells);
                else if(numberOfMinesNear > 0){
                    openedEmptyCells = checkForEqualVal([numberOfMinesNear, idNumericPart], openedEmptyCells);
                }
                else{

                    openedEmptyCells = checkForEqualVal([false, idNumericPart], openedEmptyCells);
                    for(i=0; i<canditateCells.length; i++){
                        matchedBtw = false;
                        for(j=0; j<emptyCells.length; j++){
                            if(canditateCells[i] == emptyCells[j])
                                matchedBtw = true;
                                break;
                        }
                        if(!matchedBtw)
                            openedEmptyCells = logic_game(canditateCells[i], randomMinesLocation, openedEmptyCells);
                    }
                }
            return openedEmptyCells;    
        }

        function printToScreen(value, idNumericPart){

                if(typeof(value) === 'boolean' && value){
                    document.getElementById("num_" + idNumericPart).parentElement.innerHTML = '<b>Boom</b>';   
                }
                else if(typeof(value) === 'number'){
                    document.getElementById("num_" + idNumericPart).parentElement.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
                    document.getElementById("num_" + idNumericPart).parentElement.innerHTML = value;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("num_" + idNumericPart).parentElement.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
                    document.getElementById("num_" + idNumericPart).parentElement.innerHTML = '';       
                }
        }

        function get_button(id){
            // clear the button ID stack so we can track recursive calls per button click to assure that will only be one call per id per button game;
            idStack = [];
            console.log('get_button('+ id + ')');
            idNumericPart = id.substring(4);
            checkValue = document.getElementById("check").checked;
            matchCheckForMineProtect = false;

            if(checkValue){

                for(i=0; i<mineProtecition.length; i++){

                    if(mineProtecition[i] == idNumericPart){

                        matchCheckForMineProtect = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(matchCheckForMineProtect){
                    mineProtecition.splice(i, 1);
                    valueToBeSubstitude = '<button id="' + id + '" onclick="get_button(this.id)"></button>';
                }
                else{
                    mineProtecition.push(idNumericPart);
                    valueToBeSubstitude = '<button id="' + id + '" style="background: url(' + 'flag.png' + ') no-repeat; background-size: 40px 40px;" onclick="get_button(this.id)"></button>';
                }

                document.getElementById(id).parentElement.innerHTML = valueToBeSubstitude;
            }
            else {
                matchProtected = false;
                for(i=0; i<mineProtecition.length; i++){

                    if(mineProtecition[i] == idNumericPart){
                        matchProtected = true;
                        break;
                    }   
                }

                if(!matchProtected){

                    result = logic_game(idNumericPart, randomMinesLocation);
                    for(i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                        printToScreen(result[i][0], result[i][1]);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```